# Clean URL with Rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, clean-urls

i want to make

```
mysite.com/photo.php?id=l0el2rwbFj7kGG3
```

become

```
mysite.com/photo/l0el2rwbFj7kGG3
```

The rewrite i am using is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^photo/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) photo.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it right (almost). Just change your code by this:

```
RewriteRule ^photo/(.+)$ photo.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Hmm that's not working for me either :/  It's giving back a 404

Comment: What URI did you try? Does this URI `/photo.php?id=l0el2rwbFj7kGG3` directly work from your browser?

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled/loaded in `httpd.conf`?

Comment: Oh great to know. Please don't forget to accept this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

try this more easy one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^photo/(.*)$ photo.php?id=$1
```